cp --reflink on btrfs fixed a broken video file. What is going on?
This is one of the strangest things I've ever experienced on Linux. I had downloaded a series of video files using Transmission BT. When I tried to open the first file using Celluloid, I got an "unrecognized file type" error. So after checking local data in Transmission, it turned out that some of the data was broken and had to be downloaded again. So far, so good. But there were no seeds and I was impatient, so I thought I'd try to see if VLC could fix the problem for me. I didn't want to operate on the original file, so I created a copy.
This is where it gets really weird for me. I created a copy of the file using "cp --reflink original.mkv test.mkv" but then I accidentally opened it with Celluloid rather than VLC. However, to my surprise, the file just worked. I thought maybe Transmission had coincidentally downloaded the missing data, but it hadn't. I tried opening the original file and it wouldn't work.
Then I created a copy using "cp original.mkv test2.mkv" and this file did not work! md5sum gives me the same hash for the original file and the reflink file, but a different one for the full copy, which is also strange to me. By the way, it's an NVMe device.
Does anyone have a theory on what on Earth is happening here? I mean, I know Btrfs is awesome, but if you had asked me if it can fix video files, I would've said that was a bit too optimistic.
There's no problem. I'm just extremely curious about what's happening. I mean, a reflink copy points to the exact same data on the storage device, right? Why on Earth would the reflink copy work when the original file doesn't?
Thanks.

Is your RAM going bad?

No, I don't think so. I've run a lot of tests and it all looks fine.
